# spring cloud stream kafka - fetches bulks and misses heartbeats

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

i am looking at a spring boot service that reads messages from apache kafka, requests the records indicated by the message from another service via http, processes them, saves some data into a database and posts the results to another topic.

this is done via

```
@StreamListener(Some.INPUT)
@SendTo(Some.OUTPUT)
```

this is done in several services and generally works just fine. The only property set is

```
spring.cloud.stream.binder.consumer.concurrency=20
```

the topic itself has 20 partitions, which should fit.

When monitoring the reads from kafka, we found really low throughput and strange behaviour:

the app reads up to 500 messages at once, followed by 1-2 minutes of nothing. during this time, the consumer repeatedly logs that it is "missing heartbeats, because the partition was rebalanced", "reassigning partitions" and sometimes even throws an exception saying that it "failed to commit, because the polling interval has elapsed"

We concluded, that this meant, that the consumer fetches 500 messages, takes to long to process all of them, misses its time window and therefore cannot commit any of the 500 messages to the broker - which reassigns the partition and resends the same messages over again.

After looking through threads and docs, i found the "max.poll.records" property, but conflicting proposals as the where to set this property.

some say to set it under

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer.<input>.configuration
```

some say

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binders.consumer-properties
```

I tried setting both to 1, but the services behaviour did not change.

How do i correctly handle the case, that the consumer cannot keep up with the required polling interval with default settings?

common-yaml:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.group=${spring.application.name}
```

service-yaml

```
spring:
  clould:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer.headerMode: embeddedHeaders
        producer.headerMode: embeddedHeaders
      bindings:
       someOutput:
         destination: outTopic
       someInput:
         destination: inTopic
           consumer:
             concurrency: 30
      kafka:
        bindings:
          consumer:
            someInput:
              configuarion:
                max.poll.records: 20 # ConsumerConfig ignores this
              consumer:
                enableDlq: true
                configuarion:
                  max.poll.records: 30 # ConsumerConfig ignores this
          someInput:
            configuarion:
              max.poll.records: 20 # ConsumerConfig ignores this
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              configuarion:
                max.poll.records: 30 # ConsumerConfig ignores this
        binder:
          consumer-properties:
            max.poll.records: 10 # this gets used first
          configuration:
            max.poll.records: 40 # this get used when the first one is not present
```

"Ignores this" always meaning, if no other property is set, ConsumerConfiguration keeps it default of 500 for max poll records

EDIT.: we have gotten closer:

The problem had to do with spring retry having the exponentialBackoffStrategy set - and a bunch of errors effectively stopping the application.

What i do not get is, we forced 200 errors by posting malformed messages to the topic in question, which leads to the app reading 200, taking ages (with the old retry config) and then commiting all 200 errors at once.

How does this make sense if we have

```
max.poll.records: 1
concurrency: 1
ackEachRecod = true
enableDlq: true # (which implicitly makes autoCommitOffsets = true according to the docs)
```

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same problem.Were you able to find the resolution to it?

Comment: yes, the answer was correct - max poll records at a high number lead to the processing taking too long, which times out the consumer, so set max poll lower and/or increase poll intervall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.consumer.<input>.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records
.
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-consumer-properties)...

> **Kafka Consumer Properties**
>
> The following properties are available for Kafka consumers only and must be prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.`
>
> ...
>
> **configuration**
>
> Map with a key/value pair containing generic Kafka consumer properties.
>
> Default: Empty map.
>
> ...

You could also increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

**EDIT**

I just tested with 2.1.0.RELEASE -  and it works as I described:

**No settings**

```
2019-03-01 08:47:59.560  INFO 44698 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 500
    ...
```

**Boot default**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42

2019-03-01 08:49:49.197  INFO 45044 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 42
    ...
```

**Binder default #1**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.max.poll.records=43

2019-03-01 08:52:11.469  INFO 45842 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 43
    ...
```

**Binder default #2**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.poll.records=43

2019-03-01 08:54:06.211  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 43
    ...
```

**Binding default**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.poll.records=43
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=44

2019-03-01 09:02:26.004  INFO 47833 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 44
    ...
```

**Binding specific**

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.poll.records=43
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=44
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=45

2019-03-01 09:05:01.452  INFO 48330 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    ...
    max.poll.records = 45
    ...
```

**EDIT2**

Here is the full test app. I simply created a new app at http://start.spring.io and selected 'Kafka' and 'Cloud Stream.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So54932453Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54932453Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=so54932453

spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.records=42
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.max.poll.records=43
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.default.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=44
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.max.poll.records=45
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.gprussell</groupId>
    <artifactId>so54932453</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so54932453</name>
    <description>Demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: i read that, too, what made me unsure is, that setting the "binder.consumer-properties" to 20 and the one you mention to 10 - the one that actually shows up in org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig, is 20. while we did not find the config that takes the value of 10. Are these two properties unrelated and just happen to be called identically?

Comment: There is a hierarchy. Boot (`spring.kafka.consumer.properties...`) then binder defaults, then binding defaults, then specific binding, so the binding should win. What version of the binder are you using? Can you edit the question to show your `.properties/.yml`?

Comment: i updated the question and added all properties I've tried by now - non of them has had an effect on the behavior i always get these "read a lot, read nothing for 2 minutes" loop

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the version; I just tested it and it works as I described; see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, wenn are using boot 2.1.0 and Cloud greenwich. funnily enough, i do not get these o.a.k. logs at all, i verified the config by adding a breakpoint to the consumerconfig constructor. Are we simply missing an annotation to activate some autoconfig? We just have EnableBindings set

Comment: You should see `org.apache.kafka` with Boot's default logging configuration (no `logback.xml`) so something else is going on. I have edited the answer to show my complete test app.

Comment: is do see the packages logs, eg. i get multiple instances of "o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: ..." and  i just do not get "ConsumerConfig" in the logs - and even when i set the property that gets loaded by the config - the sonsumer still does "commit X messages, idle for almost exaclty 4 minutes, commit x messages" with X decreasing very slightly over time. I cannot find where these 4 minutes come from - no interval is configured to be 4 minutes, but you can count on this interval being stable.

Comment: I just realized, consumerConfig logs to info, but it does not show on the console or logfile, while AdminClientConfig uses the same method to log (from the AbstractConfig class) and shows up. What ever that is about - i have 1 minutes poll interval set and 1 max poll records - i don#t see what makes the app wait 4 minutes like  these pauses are scheduled somewhere

Comment: we had kind of a "breakthrough" - i edited the question

Comment: The exponential backoff (total time) must not exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms`. I don't understand your follow-on question. This discussion has exceeded what the moderators here consider acceptable. I suggest you start a new question and provide much more information (configuration, logs etc).